# Calculate DAX measure for row total by ignoring strings

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

looking for a help to calculate total on each row by ignoring strings at power bi (DAX)

I need to add few column values which is a combination of number & text and show the sum in the column "Total" as shown in the here ([Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyGu2.png))

the condition i required is, if any of the value in the respective rows has text value then I need to avoid it and add the remaining only numbers

[SAMPLE DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olB3.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyGu2.png)

Tried the below measure just for one column but since am using filter, its eliminating the rows which contain SL but i required remaining data totals just by ignoring particular strings(cell value)

```
Measure = 
var data = SUMX(FILTER(Append1, Append1[7/6/2023]<>"SL"), VALUE(Append1[7/6/2023]))
    
return data
```

looking for suggestions!!

Comment: First step is to unpivot your data so you have (Name, Date, Qty) or whatever the value is. Your table design is wrong for PowerBI.

Comment: Then create a new column using ISNUMERIC() and ane substitute a value of zero for any non-numeric values. Then you can do math on that

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps in Power Query

1. First Unpivot columns other than Name to form Name, Date, Value columns
2. Delete top seven rows
3. Write a custom column to replace if text presents then with zero

`custom = if Value.Is([Value],type number) then [Value] else 0)`

4. Then Group by Name to display Total for each Name.

Here is M code

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data18jul23.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}, {"Column5", type any}, {"Column6", type any}, {"Column7", type any}, {"Column8", type any}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Name", type text}, {"5/22/2023", type any}, {"5/23/2023", type any}, {"5/24/2023", type any}, {"5/25/2023", type any}, {"5/26/2023", type any}, {"5/27/2023", type text}, {"5/28/2023", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",7),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Custom", each if Value.Is([Value],type number) then [Value] else 0),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Name"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Custom]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]